# Why isn't this jQuery working to hide the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery:

```
$('.resume-header').hover(
        function() {
            $('resume-header img').css('display', 'none');
            $('resume-header img').attr('src', 'media/resume-icon-download.png');
            $('resume-header img').fadeIn(400);
        },
        function() {
            $('resume-header img').css('display', 'none');
            $('resume-header img').attr('src', 'media/resume-icon.png');
            $('resume-header img').fadeIn(400);
        }
    );
```

Note, all my other jQuery is working.

Here's the HTML corresponding to it:

```
            <div class="header">
                <div class="me-header">
                    <a href="#"><img src="media/me-icon.png" alt="Picture of Christian Selig"><br> <span class="center-text">Contact Me</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="resume-header">
                    <a href="resume.pdf"><img src="media/resume-icon.png" alt="Resume icon" title="Click to download resume (PDF)"><br> <span class="center-text">Resume (PDF)</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `$('resume-header img')` should be `$('.resume-header img')`.  Note the `.`.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a valid selector?

```
$('resume-header img')
```

Are you missing a dot?

```
$('.resume-header img')
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the dot for class selector

*Change*

```
 $('resume-header img').css('display', 'none');
```

*To*

```
 $('.resume-header img').css('display', 'none');
```